# Where is the Source Code for Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, strongly-typed-helper

I am currently browsing the source code of asp.net mvc 3 I just downloaded from codeplex. I'm particularly interested in seeing the source code of strongly typed Helper methods like TextBoxFor and DropDownListFor but failed to locate them in InputExtensions.cs and elsewhere.

Would someone point out where I can find required code? My purpose is to see how these helper methods add Html 5's data-* attributes to different input elements on the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx) (version 6. should be somewhere available for free), open `System.Web.Mvc.dll` and search for `InputExtensions`

or

Get [mvc source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781), open in visual studio, and search for `InputExtensions`

edit: misread the question..

I guess you are looking for `InputExtensions.cs line: 371`

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));
```

Comment: Agreed, apart from use of reflector since RedGate took over :p I recommend folk try alternatives like: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/christophwille/archive/2011/02/16/new-from-sharpdevelop-ilspy.aspx

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to download the source code or use reflector extensions.

If you "go to definition" (<kbd>F12</kbd>), you should see the file metadata, which is the summarized method declarations.  From there, hover over the tab, and you should see the (local) file path where the method came from, which also corresponds to the namespace.  With that, you'll be able to look it up from the MVC source code on Codeplex:

[http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/**System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions**.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)